# UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 CryptCodecOpener

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

While using Java 7 I used to connect to MS Access by using the JDBC-ODBC Bridge, but now I'm using Java 8 with UCanAccess and I'm running into some issues. I have 2 classes:

1. CryptCodecOpener class

   ```
   package javaapplication1;


   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.JackcessOpenerInterface;
   import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.CryptCodecProvider;
   import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
   import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;

   public class CryptCodecOpener implements JackcessOpenerInterface {
        @Override
   public Database open(File fl,String pwd) throws IOException {
      DatabaseBuilder dbd =new DatabaseBuilder(fl);
      dbd.setAutoSync(false);
      dbd.setCodecProvider(new CryptCodecProvider(pwd));
      dbd.setReadOnly(false);
      return dbd.open();
   }

   }
   ```

and

2. JavaApplication1 class

   ```
   package javaapplication1;
   import java.sql.*;
   public class JavaApplication1 {
   static Connection con;
   static Statement st;
   static PreparedStatement pst;
   static ResultSet rs;

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       // TODO code application logic here

       try
       {
           //Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String env=System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\test.accdb;jackcessOpener=CryptCodecOpener";
        //String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+env+"\\RSSBV0\\db\\rssboffdb.accdb";
        //String username="";
        String username=System.getProperty("user.name");
        String password="r$$b231";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,username,password);
        String query = "select username from userstb";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = null;

        try
        {
           rs = pst.executeQuery();

           while(rs.next())
           {
               System.out.println(rs.getString("username"));
           }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          pst.close();
          con.close();
        }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }


   }

   }
   ```

Both classes are in the same packages but when I'm trying to run it, this following error comes up:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 CryptCodecOpener

Can anyone help me and give me advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jackcessOpener` parameter requires the fully-qualified name of the class that implements `JackcessOpenerInterface`, even if that class is in the same package as the class that invokes it. So your connection URL

```java
String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\test.accdb;jackcessOpener=CryptCodecOpener";
```

is incomplete. You need to use

```java
String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\test.accdb;jackcessOpener=javaapplication1.CryptCodecOpener";
```

Also, be aware that you may have insufficient permissions to work with the database file if it is stored in the root folder of a system drive (`C:\`). You really should move the database file to another location where you can be sure that you will have full read/write access.

Comment: Thanks Thompson for your help. The issue is now resolved with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved by install :
`UcAnaccess` library version 4.0.4

if you are using maven you can use the following :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ucanaccess/ucanaccess -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
  <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and `Jackcess` library version 1.1.10 ,and also `jackcess-encrypt` library with version 3.0.0.

Maven :

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jackcess/jackcess -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jackcess</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.healthmarketscience.jackcess/jackcess-encrypt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackcess-encrypt</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

to try java code :

```
  public static void tryit() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
          Connection conn = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\aag\\Desktop\\F_B_1.mdb;jackcessOpener=com.floridatrading.mobile_app.mobileapp.manage.CryptCodecOpener");
    
          System.out.println("Successfully");
          conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```